# How to count the number of entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM red_kat ORDER BY ID DESC';
$category = mysql_query($sql);

while ($cat = mysql_fetch_array($category)) 
{

$category_title = $cat['nazwa'];
$category_url = $cat['slug'];
$idcat =  $cat['id'];
$zapytanie = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT('.$idcat.') FROM red_kat_id');
$ile=mysql_result($zapytanie, 0, 0);
echo '<li class="cat-item cat-item-1">';
echo "<a href='http://".$domena."".$slug_category."".$category_url."".$koncowka_category."'>".$category_title."</a> (".$ile.")";
echo '</li>';
}
```

How using "join" count the number of entries for this category?

My database:
id_kategorii = id cat and id_wpisu = id entry

```
    id_kategorii    id_wpisu
        1             379
        2             378
        1             377
        1             376
        2             375
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and desire output. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok thanks.. 
I corrected

Comment: @Drew *This*, on the other hand, is a definite contender ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to count count your records. add your join statement and it should work for you :)

```
SELECT column, Count(*) as Count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY column 
ORDER BY column ASC
```

You can also read a similar question here [Select count(*) and "join" over 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152262/select-count-and-join-over-3-tables) that should give you an answer on how to join/count multiple tables (assuming thats what you're referring to with your JOIN statement)

Comment: and where is your `group by`?

Comment: Right therrrreee :) got a phone call as I was typing it out slipped a little lol

Comment: It wasnt there, I forgot to add it until you mentioned lol :)

Comment: Ohh for a moment I tougth need new glasses

Comment: *rubs head, I believe you still may* LOL, okay enough. :P Hope this works for @Matt